# class not returning correct value from set and get methods C++

Tags: c++, class

First timer here i hope i dont bum you out with what is possibly a simple solution. still pretty new to c++. I will first just give you the code and we can go from there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std ;

class Point // class point will have an x and a y value 
{
public:
// should contain attributes of a single point 
double x ; // x value
double y ; //y value
double f ; //importance factor

//constructor
Point (double xpoint, double ypoint)// can accept two agruments
{
    x = xpoint ;
    y = ypoint ;
}

//default constructor 
Point ()
{
    x = 7;
    y = 8;
}

//set methods
void setX (double pointx)
{
    x = pointx;
}

void setY (double pointy)
{
    y = pointy ;
}

void setF(double inF)
{
    f = inF ;
}

//get methods for retyening values to main
double getX()
{
    return x; // return the X form the setX
}

double getY ()
{
    return y ; // return the y from the setY
}

//return the importance factor
double getF ()
{
    return f ;
}

};

//global fucntion that takes three objects as arguments 
static void calculateF (Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)// not sure if this syntax for         objects as arguments is correct?.. seems to work ok
{
double F ; // i now have an f in the class and in the method? do i need both?

double xPoint1 = p1.getX(); // x value of object p1
double yPoint1 = p1.getY(); // y value of object p1
double xPoint2 = p2.getX(); // x value of object p2
double yPoint2 = p2.getY(); // y coordinates of object p2 
double xPoint3 = p3.getX(); // x coordinates of obejct p3
double yPoint3 = p3.getY(); // y coorinates of obejct p3

//equation for working out f from these six values
//temp variables to store the length of the triangles sides.
double p2p3 = sqrt (((xPoint2 - xPoint3)*(xPoint2 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint2 - yPoint3)*(yPoint2 - yPoint3))); //length point2 to point1 (PR in assingment notes)
cout << "p1p2 is = " << p2p3 << endl; // print the value of p2p3 (PR) 
double p1p2 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint2)*(xPoint1 - xPoint2)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint2)*(yPoint1 - yPoint2))); //length point1 to point 2 (LP in assingment notes)
cout << "p1p2 is = " << p1p2 << endl;
double p1p3 = sqrt (((xPoint1 - xPoint3)*(xPoint1 - xPoint3)) + ((yPoint1 - yPoint3)*(yPoint1 - yPoint3)));//length of point1 to point 3 (LR in assigment notes) 
cout << "hypotenuse p1p3 is = " << p1p3 << endl; 

F = p1p2 + p2p3 - p1p3 ; //equation for f
cout << "importance factor is " << F << endl ;
p2.setF(F); // unsure what this is meant to do??? setting F to f in class, not working 
}

int main ()
{
// create objects of type Point, passing different x and y values to the contructor

Point point1 (7,5); // new point object point1 with value x=2.5, y=5.3
Point point2 (4,8); // second point obejct 
Point point3 (8,9); // third point object 

//then call calculateF fucntion
calculateF(point1, point2, point3);
cout << "point 2 has f value of: " << point2.getF() << endl ; // returning a random number ie not f

system ("PAUSE");
return 0 ;

}
```

the objects i am creating are points of a shapes boundary which have an x and y coordinates and also an importance factor which is calculated using some trig and vector maths (in calculateF).

I need the f value of the class Point to return to main after i have set it using the setF fucntion called it from the global fucntion caclculateF. Now the F value in the calculateF method is being caluculated correctly and being displayed accordingly. However when i call f using getF from main it just displays a random number (perhaps a memory address?) So something must be wrong with my class set up, my set or get methods for f. But as they are the same as the get and set methods for x and y, i cant see why its not returning the correct value in main. Go ahead and copy it and run it yourself.

Any and all help regarding this troubling matter would be greatly appreciated 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the Point objects by value, which means that copies of the objects get passed to the `calculateF` method, and any changes to that copy will only be seen locally in the `calculateF` method.

Change the signature of `calculateF` to accept a reference to a Point for the point2 parameter:

```
static void calculateF(Point p1, Point& p2, Point p3)
{
...
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately that doesnt seem to be doing the trick Willem. Is there nothing else i have to alter to accomidate for the reference? also do i not need to be using pointers instead of variables to pass a reference?

Comment: Works in my case. And should in yours too. On return the point2.getF() is 4.24264. The only alteration is for the second parameter to accept a reference, that is: If it's the value of second parameter you're interested in.  As for references vs. pointers: The difference between the two is too much to explain here, and there are people way more qualified than I to do that, a quick google will yield tons of results. In a very tiny nutshell, and not nearly accurate: Think of a reference as an alias to a variable.

Comment: I understand the basic prinicples and the difference in passing by value, passing by address, and passing by reference. And i do apoligise, i had made other alterations in my code beofre the one you suggested and forgot to remove them :|. and it does in fact work

Comment: while i have you here Willem might as well chance another answer :) what i need to do now is store these objects in a <list> and then Navigate through the list repeatedly calling the global function calculateF each time passing 3 objects so that all objects get assigned an f value. i then need to navigate the list and find and remove the point object lowest f value. Dont mean to be cheeky here, just hoping for a bit of guidance.

Comment: Start by reading up on std::vector, and if you have trouble, post a new question. That way, it's visible for the whole community, and maybe you won't even need to ask anything :). 
(That, and my time is also limited, I probably can't wrap it up on short notice ;) ) 
Good luck!